# General Visit visa enquire for Italy

Tags: visas, italy

Me and my wife want to go to Italy for 1 week holiday. What document do we need to have? I visited England before, will that help me to get tourist visa for Italy?

Comment: What are yours and you wife's nationality?

Comment: My nationality is indian

Comment: If i show  my dad as a sponsor so it will good for my visa or no

Comment: The equivalent to the UK General visit visa for Italy is a called a "Schengen” “short-stay” or “type C” visa. You should find plenty of information about it on this site and elsewhere on the web (including on the website of the relevant Italian consulate).

Answer (score 1):

You (an Indian) and your wife (assuming she is also a visa national) should both go to the [Italian consular web site](http://www.vfs-italy.co.in/) and create applications.

There is guidance on that site which explains what sort of documents they need as additional evidence.

For your other question: **I visited England before, will that help me to get tourist visa for Italy?**, they like a good performance history.  It may depend upon how current your history is, but overall they like it.

Comment: I also think that India and UK have less bureaucracy, because India always was in economic and politic relationship with UK.